# Android call activity in other package doesn't work

Tags: android, package, start-activity

I'm trying to start an activity in another package, I already saw a lot of answers on the topic, but the answers I found don't seem to work for me.

Here how I call the other activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.packageroot.package2", "com.packageroot.package2.MainActivity");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

And here my Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.packageroot" >

<application
       <activity
            android:name=".package1.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.packageroot.package2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:parentActivityName=".package1.MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".package1.MainActivity"/>

        </activity>
```

And I still get this error:

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.packageroot.package2/com.packageroot.package2.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your manifest?

What I don't get is that the path indicated is the error is exactly the name of the activity...

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the package to the build.gradle file under dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.packageroot.package2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
intent.setClassName("com.packageroot.package2", "com.packageroot.package2.MainActivity");
```

to

```
intent.setClassName("com.packageroot", "com.packageroot.package2.MainActivity");
```

The first parameter is "package name".
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

If your intent go through packages,this is what you should do.
In your Manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:exported="true">//got to declare this
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="YOUR ACTION NAME" />
            //At least one category,use DEFAULT if you don't have one
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And in your Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(YOUR ACTION NAME);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

Best Solution Work for me is controlling the back Button

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecoundActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```